# Encoding Permutations With Repeating Values

Tags: algorithm, combinations, permutation, combinatorics

I'm trying to generate all combinations of A,B,C,D,E in three positions:

```
A,A,A
A,A,B
C,A,E
C,B,A
C,B,B
etc...
```

I've learned about factorial number systems and combinatorial number systems, but I'm still stuck finding the right implementation. Generally in the past I've used recursion to solve this problem, but in this case I don't want to generate the whole list to find one value, so I need an encoding.

Ideally I have an integer encoding for the combinations, so I can simply call a function with an iteration integer to generate the correct permutation.

Also what is this called and how can I learn more about the variations in approaches? Some similar solutions I've seen generate only non-repeating combinations (ABC,ABD) others don't reuse values.

My guess based on my past recursion approach is that `permutation(0)` would result in `aaa` and `permutation(100)` would result in `adw`.

Comment: These are called [Combinations with repetition](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations_with_repetitions).  There are plenty of good implementations there to get you started.

Comment: In fact, here is [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50177938/9898745) that has a solution for your case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a function to generate a specific n Multichoose r combination, given the index number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50148010/is-there-a-function-to-generate-a-specific-n-multichoose-r-combination-given-th)

Comment: Thanks @Emil the link is to a solution I'm looking for! The "n Multichoose r" version I think is what I need. Where can I go about learning more about this type of problem? I think I may have found something here:
https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis160/current/files/lecture/ln05.pdf

Comment: Are you looking for combinations or permutations? If `A,A,B` is different from `B,A,A`, then you're looking for [permutations with repetition](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Permutations_with_repetitions)

Comment: Thanks for the question, although I didn't understand it at the time, I am in fact looking for permutations with repetition!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific combinations you look for seem to be just "any of A,B,C,D,E on each position".
In this case, they are much akin a "pentary" (base 5) [positional numeral system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_numeral_system): you have three digits, and each of them may independently be 0 (A), 1 (B), 2 (C), 3 (D), or 4 (E).
The same goes for encoding these as integers: just number them from 0 to 5<sup>3</sup>-1.

For a number k, the "combination" is "(k div 5<sup>2</sup>) mod 5, (k div 5<sup>1</sup>) mod 5, (k div 5<sup>0</sup>) mod 5, with `ABCDE` encoded as `01234`, respectively.

For a "combination" like "xyz", first map letters `ABCDE` to digits `01234` as x, y, and z, and then the encoding number is x*5<sup>2</sup> + y*5<sup>1</sup> + z*5<sup>0</sup>.

Comment: This is for permutations. The number of combinations of a set of 5 chosen 3 at time should only return 35 results.

Comment: @Emil The examples given are not combinations, in the combinatorial sense. See `A, A, B` and `C, A, E`.

Comment: Agreed, however it seems right now that we need more clarification

Comment: Thanks @Gassa is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50148010/is-there-a-function-to-generate-a-specific-n-multichoose-r-combination-given-th an example implementation of what you described? I'm still reviewing and understanding it myself.

Comment: @Blaine. No. If you want combinations with repetitions ("how much Bs" matters, "where are Bs" does not matter), go with the answer you linked. If positions are also important ("ABB" is different from "BBA"), go with my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Here's the solution I wrote up: https://play.golang.org/p/aneADJMSqxA